# Enviar archivo de un formulario via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

El problema es que no entra al primer **IF**, osea que la variable **$_FILE[]** la esta enviando como **null**, en otras palabras esa variable la esta enviando vacía y no sé si hay alguna forma de pasar el array o  es de manera diferente o que estoy haciendo mal.

Esto es el form el input es el  de archivo

```
 echo '<div class="panel-body" >';
 echo '<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()">&times;</button>';

    echo'<center>   <h4 class="modal-title">Registro</h4>
        <form style="height: 400px; width: 90%; ;" id="win"   method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Nombre del Consultor:</label>
            <div style="height: 50px; width: 100%; ">                           
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control col-xs-5  input-lg">
            </div>

            <label>Numero de Empleado:</label>
            <div style="height: 50px; width: 100%; ">                           
                <input type="text" name="numero" class="form-control col-xs-5  input-lg" required="required">
            </div>

            ';


            echo '<label>Proyecto:</label>
                <div style="height: 70px; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <select style="display: inline-block;" name="proyecto" class="form-control col-xs-5  input-lg">';

                     $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from proyecto") or die (mysql_error());
                     while ($resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$resultado['id'].'">'.$resultado['nombre'].'</option>
                            ';
                        }
                echo '</select>';

            echo'</select>
            </div>


            <label>Fecha de Ingreso:</label>    
            <div style="height: 70px; width: 100%; margin-top: -5px;">
                <input type="date" style="display: inline-block;" name="fecha"  class="form-control col-xs-5 input-lg" required="required">
            </div>


        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                Documentos <input type="file"  name="archivo[]" id="archivo" multiple="true" accept="application/pdf, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword" required="required" style="display: none;">
            </label>
        </div>  


              <div style="height: 70px; width: 100%; ">
            <button id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    ';
      echo '</center></div>
  </div>
  </div>';
 echo '</div>';
```

la parte de ajax donde no se si se envie de esa manera el array, junto con los datos del formulario.

```
$('body').ready(function () {

$('#win').on('submit', function (e) {

var dataToSend =  $(this).serialize(); //Aqui ya tenemos el contexto del formulario por eso usamos $(this)

// Despues hacemos el $.ajax
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST', // Metodo a utilizar POST, GET, etc...
    url: 'agregarsied.php', // URL de la pagina que recibira la petición
    data: dataToSend, // Aqui van los datos a enviar, en este caso serializamos los campos del formulario y los asinamos a esta variable por eso solo ponemos esta variable
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.length==0)
        {
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Ha sido Registrado',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2500
            }).then(function() {
                //alert('wi');
                window.location.href="sied.php";
                console.log(data);
            });

            //Swal({type: 'success', title: 'Bienvenido', showConfirmButton: false, timer: 1500},function(){window.location="pro_esp.php";});
        }
            else if(data.length == 1)
        {

            Swal.fire("Error","El numero de empleado ya existe","error").then(function() {
                //alert('wi');
                window.location.href="sied.php";
                console.log(data);
            });
            console.log(data);

        } else if(data.length == 2)
        {

            Swal.fire("Error","El campo de Documentos esta vacio","error").then(function() {
                //alert('wi');
                window.location.href="sied.php";
                console.log(data);
            });
            console.log(data);

        }
        else
        {

            Swal.fire("Error","No se puedo guardar la informacion","error").then(function() {
                //alert('wi');
                window.location.href="sied.php";
                console.log(data);
            });
            console.log(data);

        }
        // swal ( "¡ Aquí está el título! " , " ... ¡y aquí está el texto! " ) ;
        //console.log(data); // Este callback  responde como un status 200: OK, y lo que imprimas en php lo cachara en la variable data.
    },
    error: function (data) {
        Swal.fire("ERROR","Ocurrió un error al actualizar  la Información","error");
        console.log(data);
        // Este callback  responde con status de error, e.g. 400, 404, 500, etc...
    }
});


return false;
// Este return es para que no se lanze el evento submit al navegador y no brinque de pagina, si no que se queda esperando la respuesta de nuestra llamada ajax.
  });

});
```

y en el php  creo que estoy tomando los datos de buena manera pero en los logs me manda que la variable archivo  esta indefinida.

```
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
 $numero=$_POST['numero'];
 $proyecto=$_POST['proyecto'];
 $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];

if (isset( $_FILES['archivo'])) {


$correo = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from usuarios where correo = '$correo'") or die (mysql_error());
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$usuario = $res['id'];

      $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from consultor where num_empleado = '$numero'");

    if ($res=mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {
  echo "1";

}else{

    $insertar = "INSERT INTO consultor (nombres, num_empleado, id_proyecto, estatus, fehca_in, id_usuarios) VALUES ('$nombre',   '$numero', '$proyecto', 'Activo', '$fecha', '$usuario')";


  $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $insertar);

if (!$resultado) {
    echo "Error al registrar los datos";
}else{

  }
}


 }else{
echo "22";
   }
```

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, graciasp or tu aporte. pero de igual forma me sigue mandando vació  el  campo de archivo.

Comment: En lugar de esto var dataToSend =  $(this).serialize();  seria eso o aqui data: dataToSend ?

Comment: Perfecto, con eso se soluciono el problema.  te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al enviar un Archivo via AJAX debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Crear un [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData),
2. Cambiar el `contentType` para evitar que por defecto sea `application/json` , cuando se envia un archivo es : `multipart/form-data;`
3. Cambiar el [processData](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) a falso para que no cambie la cabecera a `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`(Esto es propio de JQuery)

Explicado esto, muestro a continuacion como quedaria el codigo:

```
const dataToSend = new FormData(this)
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'agregarsied.php',
    processData: false, 
    contentType: false
    data: dataToSend, 
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (data) {

        console.log(data);

    }
});
```