# $request->file devuelve null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo el siguiente controlador

```
<?php    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
class ProveedorController extends Controller{ 

    public function store(Request $request){
        DB::beginTransaction();
            $file = $request->file('adjuntar_soportes');
            if ($request->hasFile('adjuntar_soportes')) {
                dd('entra');
            }
        DB::commit();
    }

}
```

tengo la siguiente modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_crear" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="form_crear" data-toggle="validator" role ="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Agregar Proveedor</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">                                    
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" name="adjuntar_soportes" id="adjuntar_soportes" class="custom-file-input">
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="adjuntar_soportes">Adjuntar</label>            
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    {{ Form::submit('Registrar', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

lo envío por ajax con la siguiente función

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al enviar el archivo, no me reconoce $request->file('adjuntar_soportes'), me dice que el campo es nulo, y si hago un dd al $request, me aparecen todos los campos menos el input....que pueda ser? he buscado y en la mayoría de casos, lo que encuentro es que debo colocar el  enctype="multipart/form-data" pero ya lo tengo en la modal, en el form

Comment: Revisa la llamada ajax, no parece ser un problema de Laravel, php o mysql. Y por favor no pongas imágenes de código, pon el código como texto

Comment: posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271862/enviar-archivo-de-un-formulario-via-ajax